# Removing classes from a .html() set variable. Jquery

Tags: jquery, removeclass

```
<div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="#" class="error">
    <input type="text" placeholder="#" class="error">
</div>  

var copylast = $('div').html();
```

I'm trying to copy the DIV but remove the class error from the copylast variable (I need to keep the classes within the original div.)

I've tried a string replace `var copylast = copylast.replace('class="error"', '')`;
 but it only removes the first instance, plus looks tacky. I'd much rather use `removeClass('error')` if possible.

Comment: if you'd much rather use `removeClass('error')`... why don't you?

Comment: @Colleen Because `.html()` returns a string, and you can't use jQuery methods on strings.

Comment: (I wasn't implying you'd use it on copylast as is. Obviously you'd have to modify the code a bit so you're getting the actual element instead of the html. OP just said he wanted to use it without any explanation of why he wasn't already)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [.clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) if you don't want to manipulate the DOM.

```
var copylast = $('div').clone().find('input').removeClass('error').end().html();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
copylast.find('input').removeClass('error');
```

EDIT::

This is what is should be:

```
var copylast = $('div').clone().find('input').removeClass('error').end().html();
```

Comment: `.html()` returns a string.. not a jQuery object.

Comment: @Vega I was just pointing out the way to remove the class after the element has been created

Comment: `var copylast = $('div').html();` is what in OP. You should probably fix that before doing `.find('input').removeClass('error')`

Comment: You can still edit this.. because that was the only problem and I think `.find` is what he is looking for.